# Samsung printer not working since 14.04

Tags: printing

My Samsung ml-1640 was working while using 13.10. Since I made an upgrade to 14.04 I can install the printer, but the it dosen't print. Status is :"Waiting for printer to be available".

I tried the drivers deliverd with Ubuntu, as well as the Samsung ones.

Comment: I have also problems with Samsung ML-1640 and Ubuntu 14.04. I was not able to install the Samsung driver to my 64 bit Ubuntu 14.04 machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have found the solution for this at last. I had the same problem with Samsung printer ML-1670, which stopped working since I installed Ubuntu 14.04 and thought it was a problem specific to this Ubuntu release, but it is not.

As you can see [here](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/247736), this is a problem caused by the latest version of the Samsung Universal Linux Driver (ULD) V1.00.21, released on 12 March 2014.

What you have to do is simply download the previous version of the Samsung ULD (V1.00.06 of 6 August 2013) which can be found [here](http://www.samsung.com/ca/support/model/ML-1865W/XAA-downloads#), under the section "Driver". Don't worry that this is not your exact printer model, as ULD is a package which includes all Samsung printer drivers. I have tested it with my printer and it works flawlessly.

Comment: @user268408 Did this work for you?

Comment: And for you @Jaakko?