# On Kubuntu, how do I install my Samsung ML-1640 printer?

Tags: drivers, kubuntu, printing

I installed Kubuntu on my laptop and now I want to install my printer drivers. I tried from System Configuration and by selected printers. Then, my laptop detected my printer, but when I searched for the driver, there was not driver for my printer (ML-1640) in the list.

Can you help me to install the packages? I begin with Kubuntu, by the way.

Thank you very much,

Pierre-Olivier

Comment: Is yours `XEE` or `SEE`?

Comment: try the solutions here https://askubuntu.com/questions/449003/samsung-printer-not-working-since-14-04

Comment: Updated answer for your printer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get you driver from [here](http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/model/ML-1670/XEU/) from the `Manual Download` section click on `SEE MORE` and pick `Linux`, then follow these steps to install:

1. untar the file:

   ```
   tar -xvf uld_v1.00.36_00.91.tar.gz
   ```
2. Change into the decompressed (uld) folder and run the `install.sh` script:

   ```
   sudo ./install.sh
   ```
3. When presented with a license agreement press <kbd>Space bar</kbd> to scroll a page at a time then accept with a <kbd>y</kbd> at the end of it. Follow the prompt to install it.

Comment: The model of my printer is not available. Is there something I can do?

Comment: It is, is it not ML-1640?

Comment: Argh, I screwed it Up... My printer is a ML-1670!

Comment: @Pierre-OlivierParise see my update and your owe me for the other download, get from you when we meet :-)

Comment: Thanks, I install the pilote. Now, I will give you some news if I can print with my computer this evening. Since then, thanks a lot for your help! It's really appreciated :)

Comment: It works!! Only one problem, I can't set the printer to both sides. However, thank you a lot for your help!!!! :D

Answer (score 0):

I just found that the splix package includes drivers for ML 1640. Worked like a breeze on my Raspberry Pi Debian. It should work well on Kubuntu as well.

run

```
sudo apt-get install splix
```

Answer (score 0):

For older samsung printers (like ml-16**) on newer ubuntu versions (like 20 or 21) you can use `sudo apt install printer-driver-splix`